# changing color based on id using CSS and html

Tags: html, css

I have this html simple code :

```
<li id="365720">
    <a target="_self" href="">nice</a>
</li>
```

with the id of `#365720`, how I could change the color of the word nice using CSS?

I tried a couple of things like using the id it self our target the id with `id*$^` and still I could not manage to change the color of the word

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In HTML 4, `id` must begin with a letter. (HTML5 does allow this, you can painfully follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088857/2333214) if you really want to go that way). A much more practical way would be to use use a `data-*` attribute instead of `id` like the following:

```css
[data-id="365720"] a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li data-id="365720">
  <a target="_self" href="">nice</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the number for id.
The following is working.

```css
#li-box a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li id="li-box">
  <a target="_self" href="">nice</a>
</li>
```

Comment: can i change the id name from the css file ?

Comment: you can't change the id name from the css file.